# Fractions in equation mode

Tags: math-mode, equations

I don't want to double up other questions and this is probably a quick one for somebody that uses `math` mode more often than me (I pretty much started today)

Can someone help me understand what is wrong with the syntax here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eqn:x}
$\Delta$C$_{i}$ = $(\frac{m^{a}/m^{o}}{C_{i}^{a}/C_{i}^{o}}-1) C_{i}^{o}$   
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The above produces this preview in Sublime Text 3, which is fine and just how I need the equation to look.

[image: xx]

But with it came a series of errors, which I assume is because I'm mixing `\frac` with the `equation` environment in a bad way somehow or being uneconomic with my notation.

```
"Display math should end with $$. [ $\Delta]"
"Missing $ inserted. [  $\Delta]"
"LaTeX Error: Bad math environment delimiter. [ \end{equation}]"
"You can't use `\eqno' in horizontal mode. [    \end{equation}]"
"Missing $ inserted. [  \end{equation}]"
"Display math should end with $$. [ \end{equation}]"
```

I tried for some time to understand where delimiters should go to no avail

Could someone please spare a second to help me learn to do this more sensibly?

Comment: Looks like you are using too many `$`s. There are two display modes for math-environments. In the first one you put it into running text between ONE pair of `$ .. $`. The second is when you want to put many terms in a kind of list: opening with `\[`, closing this environment with `\]`. That should remove most if not all error messages. // See e.g. here: https://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/aaksoy/latex/latexthree.html .

Comment: Removing all six instance of `$` in the interior of the `equation` environment is what's needed here. After `\begin{equation}`, LaTeX is automatically in display math mode; no need to go in and out of inline math mode via the `$` tokens.

Comment: It is a gross error of Sublime Text to preview when the syntax is incorrect.  Almost a bug .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TeX has two fundamental ways of processing material. The material can be processed either in **text mode** or in math mode. TeX's math mode has two main subcategories: **inline math mode** and **display math mode**.

One can use `$` tokens to initiate and terminate inline math mode *while in text mode*. However, after `\begin{equation}`, TeX is in display math mode automatically; while in display math mode, it's an error to try to initiate (or terminate) inline text mode.

What to do? Easy! Just get rid of all six instances of `$` in the equation. In addition, I would also tell TeX to enlarge the parentheses, by prefixing `\Bigl` to `(` and `\Bigr` to `)`.

Moral of the story? **Don't ever ignore TeX's error messages.** Just because the program somehow manages to struggle through to the end without crashing completely doesn't mean that it's ok to ignore the error messages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eqn:x}
\Delta C_{i} = \Bigl(\frac{m^{a}/m^{o}}{C_{i}^{a}/C_{i}^{o}}-1\Bigr) C_{i}^{o}   
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed, 2 years of thesis writing taught me to inspect just about every error and warning.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{eqn:x}
\Delta C_{i} = \left(\frac{m^{a}/m^{o}}{C_{i}^{a}/C_{i}^{o}}-1\right)C_{i}^{o}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

or in short:

```
\Delta C_i = \left(\frac{m^a/m^o}{C_i^a/C_i^o}-1\right)C_i^o
```

[image]